# Neo4j Cypher query: order collection, take first n elements

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm having trouble writing a Cypher query for this social networking type of application. It involves users that add posts (essentially an image with a description), which users can review.

In Cypher the graph model is this:
`(user)-[:WROTE_REVIEW]->(review)-[:EVALUATES]->(post)`

The query I'm trying to write should return all the posts that a particular user has reviewed, along with some general information about the reviews of a post.

This includes:

1. (the post's ID)
2. the post's image
3. the post's description
4. the total number of reviews of this post
5. the total number of reviewers of this post
6. **the avatars of the last 6 reviewers of this post, ordered by the date of the review, descending**

I think I've managed to complete the first five items, but item 6 is giving me trouble. The query below gives me all of the avatars, while I only need the last 6.

```
START user=node(2515)
MATCH (user)-[:WROTE_REVIEW]->()-[:EVALUATES]->(post)
WITH distinct post
MATCH (review)-[:EVALUATES]->(post)
WITH post, count(review) as reviews
MATCH (reviewer)-[:WROTE_REVIEW]->()-[:EVALUATES]->(post)
WITH post, reviews, count(distinct reviewer) as reviewers, collect(distinct reviewer.Avatar) as avatars
ORDER BY post.CreationTime DESC
RETURN post.Id, post.Image, post.Description, reviews, reviewers, avatars;
```

Can someone show me how to order the avatars by review date (i.e. `review.CreationTime`) descending, and take the first six items?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collection slices in Neo4j 2.0 were the key. I had to put in some `distinct` clauses in my results since some duplicates were coming up. This is what I ended up with:

```
START user=node(2515)
MATCH (user)-[:WROTE_REVIEW]->()-[:EVALUATES]->(post)
WITH distinct post
MATCH (review)-[:EVALUATES]->(post)
WITH post, count(review) as reviews
MATCH (reviewer)-[:WROTE_REVIEW]->(review)-[:EVALUATES]->(post)
WITH distinct post, reviewer, review, reviews
ORDER BY review.CreationTime, post.CreationTime DESC
RETURN post.Id AS postId, post.Image AS postImage, post.Description AS postDescription, reviews AS Reviews, count(distinct reviewer) AS Reviewers, collect(distinct reviewer.Avatar)[0..5] AS Avatars
```

Comment: @maryoush: I'm ordering the results of the WITH before I aggregate them in the RETURN.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of sorting the collection, you might sort the rows first and take the first 6 of the collection of the reviewers. so change the last match-with to something like this,

```
MATCH (reviewer)-[:WROTE_REVIEW]->(review)-[:EVALUATES]->(post)
With distinct post, reviewer, review
ORDER BY post.CreationTime DESC, review.CreationTime DESC
Return post, count(reviewer) as reviewers, collect(reviewer.Avatar)[0..5] as avatars
```

The access to the collection with index such as [0..5] requires the verion of 2.0 M5.

Comment: I tried using `ORDER BY` between a `WITH` and `RETURN` but it doesn't work. Which version of cypher are you using?